# How to compile libgit2 on windows using cmake?

Tags: windows, cmake, libgit2

I am trying to compile libgit2 and followed the instruction on `https://libgit2.github.com/docs/guides/build-and-link/` but lock so far.

Can someone tell me what to do?

Here is the result from my command line:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 12 2013
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- zlib was not found; using bundled 3rd-party sources.
-- LIBSSH2 not found. Set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH if it is installed outside of the default search path.
CMake Error at d:/cmake/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  d:/cmake/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  d:/cmake/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindPythonInterp.cmake:162 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:594 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/temp/gitlib/libgit2-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/temp/gitlib/libgit2-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try to google error messages? `LIBSSH2 not found. Set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ...` means that `ssh2` library is not found. `Could NOT find PythonInterp` means that `python` interpretator is not found. For correct installation you need these to be installed. (`zlib` library is also missed, but it is not required).

Comment: I understand that part, I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Python from Paython.org and install it (i.e. d:\python). Then Open your VS command line and type `PATH D:\Python\Python35-32;d:\cmake\bin;%PATH%`

That's all set now, go to your `build` folder run `cmake ..` and then `cmake --build .`

Comment: On .23.1 I cannot get the library to compile with LIBSSH2. I've not been able to set any properties like CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to get it to work. I really don't understand how to link the libssh2 library (1.7.0) in.

Answer (score 4):

libgit2 uses python (works both with versions 2 and 3 of the language) to build the tests. You can install python or ask CMake not to build the tests.

IIRC CMake will look in a few standard locations you don't necessarily need python in your path, though it doesn't hurt.

If you would rather not build the tests, you can pass `-DBUILD_CLAR=OFF` so it doesn't bother looking for python.

Comment: Sorry to not accepting your answer. You did not give me clear instruction to hook the Paython and manage to build the library. Turned out setting the path to Paython as Arash suggested was enough.

Comment: You *don't* need python, that's what I'm saying.